# SQL Server- Trigger. Update a column on one table with a count of columns from another table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Trying to learn triggers and can't seem to wrap my head around whether this is the best way to go about this. There is a total of 'tickets' that I would like to count and put into a column for an 'order'.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DAILYTICKETTOTALS    
ON db.ORDER 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO db.ORDER (
    --Finding the order they made for the day:
    SELECT * FROM db.ORDER
    WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'specific description' AND 
          CAST(CAST(CAST(GETDATE()AS float) AS int) AS datetime) =  
          CAST(CAST(CAST(db.ORDER.STARTDATE AS float) AS int) AS datetime)
          AND db.ORDER.CREATEDBY = 'Last, First'
)
SET db.ORDER.COLUMNTOTALS VALUES(  
    --Finding the total of tickets input for the day
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM db.ticket 
    WHERE CAST(CAST(CAST(db.ticket.DATE AS float) AS int) AS datetime) = 
          CAST(CAST(CAST(GETDATE()AS float) AS int) AS datetime)
          AND db.ticket.INPUTBY = 'Last, First');
```

Thanks for any help, and I appreciate you reviewing this.

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement / syntax is all wrong - it should be `INSERT INTO db.Order (list-of-columns) SELECT ...... FROM ....` - there's no `SET` in an `INSERT` statement anywhere.... (that's for `UPDATE`)

Comment: something like this?
CREATE TRIGGER DAILYTICKETTOTALS    
ON db.ORDER 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO db.ORDER (db.ORDER.COLUMNTOTALS)
    --Finding the order they made for the day:
    SELECT * FROM db.ORDER
    WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'specific description' AND 
          CAST(CAST(CAST(GETDATE()AS float) AS int) AS datetime) =  
          CAST(CAST(CAST(db.ORDER.STARTDATE AS float) AS int) AS datetime)
          AND db.ORDER.CREATEDBY = 'Last, First'

Comment: Side note: Make sure to wrap your table name in square brackets. You've used `ORDER` for some reason (ill-advised) which is a reserved key word (for obvious reasons).

Comment: There also doesnt appear to be any reference to the actual rows that have been updated, via the inbuilt INSERTED table.

Comment: @ZLK Yeah, I could have chosen a better table name for this example, but it's just a name for the example.

Comment: @ TomC The row/table I am trying to update with the count would be the first Selection where I find the order created by someone, and for that day. Again, I don't know if there's a better way to structure this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solved my problem, in case any of you were curious. I don't know if its ideal, but it works.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DAILYTICKETTOTALS    
ON db.ORDER 

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @INS NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @INS = NAMECOLUMN FROM INSERTED
WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'specific description' AND 
CAST(CAST(CAST(STARTDATE AS float) AS int) AS datetime)=
CAST(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS float) AS int) AS datetime)
END
IF @INS = ‘Last, First’

BEGIN

UPDATE db.ORDER
SET COLUMNTOTALS  =  EXAMPLENAME.CT

FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CT FROM ticket WHERE INPUTBY = ‘Last, First’) EXAMPLENAME
WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'specific description' AND INPUTBY = ‘Last, First’ 
END
BEGIN
```

Comment: This will fail! The problem is that you are assuming that there is only one row in Inserted. While that may have been the case in testing, as soon as someone does any sort of update that updates more than one row then your method wont work. You should always assume that there will be more than one row updated otherwise you will cause yorself or someone else grief in the future.

Comment: With the where clause attached to filter on the inserted I should only ever get 1. The UI being used would only allow one entry at a time anyway. And actually if for some reason they could add more inserted rows that fit that where clause, I would want the same thing to be done.

Comment: Up to you, but sooner or later someone will do a bulk fix on the table that affects a whole bunch of rows. Its never good practice to set a single variable inside a trigger like this, specially when you can do exactly the same thing by joining between INSERTED and your table, using whatever crieria you need, as per the other answer you got.  Part of SO is for education purposes. You are welcome to ignore it if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Do some research on the "Special" tables available inside a trigger, such as "INSERTED" as that will give you the details of the rows that have been updated, and you can join that to anything else (including the actual table being updated) that you need to. Remember that you should not assume there is only 1 row updated, as the trigger will fire once per batch, not once per row.

This is a version of your stored proc that assumes that each order has a unique ID named OrderID, and that both the ticket and order table have a personID rather than looking for them by name. If not, they should, and if you cant change it then use your existing messy joins.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DAILYTICKETTOTALS    
ON db.ORDER 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    update o
    set columntotals=TicketNum
    from inserted
    join db.[order] o on o.orderid=inserted.orderid
    join (
        select convert(date,ticket,[date]) as ticketdate, PersonID, count(*) as TicketNum
        from db.ticket
        group by convert(date,ticket,[date]) as ticketdate, PersonID
        ) t on t.PersonID=o.PersonID and t.ticketdate=convert(date,getdate())
```